# java model mock response json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Rest service which calls an external service.
I have this problem: the external service I call responds in two ways depending on the case of Success or Failed. This is json:

```
json{
    "result": "001",
    "status": "Success",
    "response": {
        "codiceCase": "CAS-46759-Q8P7X3",
        "guidCase": "88458d32-dd42-ec11-8c62-0022489d2f61"}
} 
OR 
{
    "result": "002",
    "status": "Failed",
    "errorManagement": {
        "errorCode": "E02",
        "errorDescription": "field not value in body"
    }
}
```

Well I created 3 simple classes:

1. class XXX...  private String result, status; .... getter & setter
2. class Response... private String codiceCase, guidCase; ... getter & setter
3. class ErrorManagement...private String errorCode, errorDescription;... getter & setter
   But when I populate with my mock, the json is always formed with the class field that I don't care for example:

```
{
    "result": "001",
    "status": "Success",
    "response": {
        "codiceCase": "CAS-46759-Q8P7X3",
        "guidCase": "88458d32-dd42-ec11-8c62-0022489d2f61"    },
        {
***"errorMessage"**: null}
}
```

How can I get only 2 of the 3 classes returned as json in my mock?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What json library are you using? Jackson?

Comment: Hi, dpr. The json response comes from an external service.

Comment: @Sergio, that does not answer @ dpr question. Which library are you using to serialize / deserialize JSON from / to Java object? Jackson? Gson?

Comment: Sorry @dpr, @ João Dias. I did not understand. I use the default Spring Boot library called by spring-boot-starter-web which should be Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you’re using Jackson to deserialize JSON as this is - I think - the default for spring.

With Jackson you can annotate the model class to omit `null` values in the JSON string representation:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Model { … }
```